# Insert textarea writed in more than one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have a textarea  and the text that i write is inserted in a p. I don't know why the text maked it's set in one line only, instead a few lines because i have an width with 300px. This only breaks the line and write in more than one line all the text if i press "enter" in the textarea to write more. For example, i write and if i press enter and write again, this breaks me the text in two lines, but i want to do this automatically, because the text it's wrapped in a `p` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I need to apply `word-break: break-word;` to my p tag.